# How to run phinx in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, migration, database-migration

I have a docker configuration (php, mysql, nginx) and I need to run [phinx](https://phinx.org/).

The problem is when I run the command `vendor/bin/phinx migrate -e development` the system not working on docker container even when I configure `phinx.yml` to that!

I have this error message:

[image: the error]

```
PDOException: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/html/.
/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/PdoAdapter.php:80
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/     /vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/PdoAdapter.php(80): PDO->__construct()
```

Which mean that phinx didn't recognize docker configurations.

**phinx.yml :**

```
paths:
    migrations: '%%PHINX_CONFIG_DIR%%/db/migrations'
    seeds: '%%PHINX_CONFIG_DIR%%/db/seeds'

environments:
    default_migration_table: phinxlog
    default_environment: development
    production:
        adapter: mysql
        host: service_mysql
        name: mydb
        user: root
        pass: '123456'
        port: 3306
        charset: utf8

    development:
        adapter: mysql
        host: service_mysql
        name: my_database
        user: root
        pass: '123456'
        port: 3306
        charset: utf8

    testing:
        adapter: mysql
        host: localhost
        name: testing_db
        user: root
        pass: ''
        port: 3306
        charset: utf8

version_order: creation
```

My question is how can I use phinx inside docker?

Comment: `not working` is never in itself a good description of the problem your are facing. Are there any error/warning messages ? What is the expected result ? What do you get instead ?

Comment: @Zeitounator, i add details, this problem come form phinx, he use machine server and not docker server.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, i should run phinx command inside docker php container :

```
sudo docker exec docker_myphp_fpm_1 vendor/bin/phinx migrate -e development
```

Answer (score 0):

Your docker containers are not in same network most probably.